# Jackson XmlMapper map XML attribute of nested element

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to parse XML into Java class and then send it to the frontend.
I am using Springboot 2.2.5, Jackson dataformat xml 2.10.2

I have following XML file:

```
<root xmlsn="...">
  <result status="1" outs="6" val="0" pic="7"/>
</root>
```

I expect this response from backend on frontend:

```
{
  status: 1,
  outs: 6,
  val: 0
  pic: 7
}
```

Well, that is super easy.

Let's see, what I have:

Class for the root element:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "...", localName = "root")
public class SetXmlResponseDto {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "result")
    private ResultPropertyDto result;
}
```

And then class for the result element ResultPropertyDto:

```
public class ResultPropertyDto {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "val", isAttribute = true)
    private String value;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "status", isAttribute = true)
    private String status;
}
```

// I removed some parts of the code for brewity (setter,getter)

But result of this is following:

```
{
  result: {
    status: 1,
    ....
  }
}
```

It is propably good to also mention how am I building it?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
objectMapper().readValue(new URL(urlAddress), SetXmlResponseDto.class);
```

Of course, I could just call `SetXmlResponseDto.getStatus()` before sending it to the frontend and output will be exactly as expected, but I was wondering, is there a way, of how to achieve required result without creating subclass `ResultPropertyDto` ??

Imagine you have 4 times nested element in XML and want to map just 1 attribute of this nested element. I would have to create 4 classes for that??

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid creating deep nested structures you could always use [xpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).

From the mentioned documentation reference:

> consider the following widget.xml file

```
<widgets>
  <widget>
     <manufacturer/>
     <dimensions/>
  </widget>
```

> The  element can be selected with the following XPath API
>   code:

```
// parse the XML as a W3C Document
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File("/widgets.xml"));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/widgets/widget";
Node widgetNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

> With a reference to the  element, a relative XPath expression
>   can now written to select the  child element:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "manufacturer";
Node manufacturerNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, widgetNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Comment: okay, this is completely different library, but I guess, this could be great for more complex file structure. In my case, it is not worth it. Anyway, thanks for your answer. I think is is a great answer